# Java regex check for matching first 4 specific characters in a file name with extension .txt

Tags: java, regex, regex-group

Need a one-line regex check for java. I have a regex:

```
(^DCLL).*\\.txt$
```

which is not working. It should match the file name given below.

> DCLL Stoneridge rock view_20171110132905.txt

Need to check first 4 characters are `DCLL` and the extension is `.txt`

Comment: `^(.{4}).*\.txt$`? Not quite sure exactly what you're looking for, but your regex works. Maybe your code (not the regex) is the problem.

Comment: [It works well](https://regex101.com/r/tz5pdd/1).

Comment: Define "not working". How did you use that regex, what results did you expect and what did you get instead?

Comment: I'm not sure if you meant to put a double backslash in the regex or if that's just some leftover escaping, but you should have `\.`, or in Java `\\.`. I noticed the double backslash after editing your question.

Comment: @ctwheels:You mean I should use \\. for java right ?

Comment: It basically should check if the first 4 characters are DCLL thats important

Comment: Did you notice you have a whitespace at the end of your expression? `(^DCLL).*\\.txt$ <-` Did you put it in the regex too or just in your question?

Comment: @Pshemo: I using (^DCLL).*\\.txt$  and it is not matching the file name DCLL Stoneridge rock view_20171110132905.txt.

Comment: @Mateus. Yes that is here not in the regex I am using. sorry for that. Its just in the question.

Comment: Could you add to the question the code you're using to validate?

Comment: @Nikhil yes `\\.` inside your Java code (escaping backslashes), but the pure regex would simply be `\.`

Comment: @ctwheels: Okay. Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your opinion guys this worked: (^DCLL).*\.txt$

Answer (score 0):

Why use regex when you can just do this?

```
s.startsWith("DCLL") && s.endsWith(".txt")
```

Comment: I am using it in this way
checkreg=(^DCLL).*\\.txt$

Comment: The problem doesn't seem to be the expression... Probably the string he's matching is not the same as the filename in the question.

Comment: This is the file name: DCLL Stoneridge rock view_20171110132905.txt

Comment: Yeah, but how are you getting that this string? I suppose you are using the wrong method to get the name (like `File#getAbsolutePath`), or you're not using the `Pattern` in the right way, so could you actually add the code to your question, please?